# Does Python have a .methods method like Ruby?

Tags: python, ruby

I'm a Ruby person migrating to Python. One thing that I miss is an easy way to see a list of all the methods that I could use on a particular object in a shell.

Is there an analogue to Ruby's [Object#methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-methods) in Python?

Answer (score 6):

Try `dir(obj)`. It gives you a list of methods associated with `obj`.